# Lambda Expressions and Method calls

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, linq-to-entities

Hi I have a collection of Objects in a Listview and i need to know if i can iterate through them with a lambda expression. and call a method on it in the expression.

Lets say i need to save a group of people to a database.

```
List<People> someList;
someList.Select(person => person.Save());
```

is this possible to do? so far i have not been able to get it working. 
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the ForEach method of a generic list:

```
List<People> someList;
someList.ForEach(person => person.Save());
```

Comment: Yeah this sounds like the perfect solution.

Comment: ForEach has always been a method of a generic List (see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=VS.80).aspx)) - it's not a Linq extension.  Although you'd have to use a delegate rather than a lambda expresssion in .net 2.0.  Which version of the .net Framework are you using?

Comment: ah i found it. turns out i was using a BindingList. but i casted to generic List and it showed up correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
someList.ForEach(p => p.Save());
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want a foreach statement:

```
foreach(People p in someList)
{
    p.Save();
}
```

But if you *really* want to do it in lambda expressions and LINQ, then your problem with the above code is that .Select(...) returns an IEnumerable/IQueryable, which creates a new query but doesn't execute your lambda expressions.

You could *force* the lambda to evaluate by calling an extension method that forces an enumeration of the data the IEnumerable/IQueryable represents. For instance by doing:

```
someList.Select(person => person.Save()).Count();
```

but this also assumes your Save() method returns non-void.

Edit: 
As others have pointed out, if you're working specifically with a List<>, then you can also do:

```
someList.ForEach(person => person.Save());
```

Comment: You select statement will be problematic in case that `Save` returns `void`.

Comment: thx. was using OP's code but added an additional note about that.

Comment: the Save did indeed return a void, but i guess thats not always going to be true.